# How to make Open SuSE - Manjaro usb key

Tags: multi-boot, opensuse, liveusb, manjaro

I am trying making a Multiboot USB key with Open SuSE 42.1 Leap and Manjaro 15.09 but it doesn't work. 
I tried with XBoot, Multibootusb, SharpBoot and YUMI, but they all failed making the USB Key. 
Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question possibly belongs on [SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ha.. sorry, i didn't know well where to post my question -.-

Comment: If you have issues regarding creating trying to create a USB Key let's say with XBoot, then post questions about the error you get here. If you are looking for software to create a Multiboot USB key, post on [SR](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I "burn" my files to USB sticks using this tool https://rufus.akeo.ie

Comment: can Rufus make multiboot USB?